# How can I override django model's delete method to save few fileds on delete

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have model **Verification**, I want to override django model's "delete()" method for this model.

And I have one more model **VerificationHistory**, which few common filed as in **Verification**.

On delete I want to save data few fields of **Verification** Model in **VerificationHistory** model.

So that I can save few model fields in different model on delete of the object is history table also.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to save object revisions, you can use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/) which does exactly that.

Check [the documentation](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on how to integrate with it.

Answer (score 0):

In `Verification` model write `delete` method. Save your data to `VerificationHistory` and call `super` of `delete`. Your `Verification` object will be delete and `VerificationHistory` Object will be created.

You will get all model methods in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#model-instance-methods)